# Decrypt PBKDF2 with OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

I need to decrypt a document with openssl:

Method : PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256  ,
Salt : saltexample ,
Passphrase : mypassphrase ,
I tried the command :

```
 openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -salt -md sha256 -in file.csv.enc -out file.csv
and also :
  openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc  -S saltexample -salt -in file.csv.enc -out file.csv
```

but i get the following error :

```
bad magic number
```

Does any one knows the correct command ?

Comment: This looks like a format error, i.e. OpenSSL does not recognize the file format you are trying to decrypt. It may not support decrypting the given file.

Comment: Can you give more information about what you know about how the file was encrypted, and what you're trying to do? PBKDF2 isn't an encryption algorithm. It stands for "password-based key-derivation function #2". As the name implies, it's an algorithm for taking a passphrase and turning it into a more suitable encryption key. So the way you asked this question makes me suspect you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on here. We'll need to clear up that misunderstanding before we can know how to help you decrypt your file.

Comment: [As I told you 2 days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62426338/decrypt-pbkdf2-with-openssl-1-0-1e) the salt must be _in the file_ in a specific format; see (my) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/3298/is-there-a-standard-for-openssl-interoperable-aes-encryption/#35614 . And you must, as you previously did, use `-pbkdf2` because it is not default.

Comment: The file is encrypted with Java, i don't have information about how it has been done except the following elements that i have been given to decrypt the file (Method : PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256 , Salt and Passphrase ).  I tried with -pbkdf2   and passing -S saltexample but i get the same error.